# SDL Small Screen

Tags: c++, sdl

When I run this code for trying to start programming a tetris clone It prints the screen to a small rectangle (<30*30) and all the other part of the screen is black (it should be green)

I know i shouldn't just give all the code but i really don't know where's the error

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

const unsigned short SCREEN_WIDTH  = 640;
const unsigned short SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const unsigned short SCREEN_BPP    = 32;

const unsigned char Block_Length   = 20;

enum Color {
    Blue = 0,
    Cyan,
    White,
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Magenta,
    Green
};

struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

struct Block {
    public:
        Point l;
        Color c;
};

vector<Block> blocks;

SDL_Surface *Screen = NULL;

void apply_surface(SDL_Surface *Source, SDL_Surface *Target, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clip = NULL);
bool init();
bool clean_up();
void show_blocks ();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    init();

    SDL_FillRect(Screen, NULL, 0x00FF00);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Block b;
        b.c = Red;
        b.l.x = i;
        b.l.y = i;
        blocks.push_back(b);
    }

    show_blocks();

    if (SDL_Flip(Screen) == -1)
        return 1;

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    clean_up();

    return 0;
}

void apply_surface(SDL_Surface *Source, SDL_Surface *Target, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clip) {
    SDL_Rect o;

    o.x = x;
    o.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(Source, clip, Target, &o);
}

bool init() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
        return false;

    if (!(Screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE)))
        return false;

    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Hey Tetris!", NULL);

    return true;
}

bool clean_up() {
    SDL_Quit();
}

void show_blocks () {
    SDL_Surface *s = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, Block_Length, Block_Length, 32, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
        Uint64 bColor;
        switch (blocks[i].c) {
            case Blue    : bColor = 0x0000FF; break;
            case Cyan    : bColor = 0x00FFFF; break;
            case White   : bColor = 0xFFFFFF; break;
            case Yellow  : bColor = 0xFFFF00; break;
            case Red     : bColor = 0xFF0000; break;
            case Magenta : bColor = 0xFF00FF; break;
            case Green   : bColor = 0x00FF00; break;
        }
        SDL_FillRect(s, NULL, bColor);
        apply_surface(s, Screen, blocks[i].l.x * Block_Length, blocks[i].l.y * Block_Length);
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the first glance, I came to the question:
Is SDL_Rect in apply_surface() set correctly? Setting just x and y without width and height gives a rect with undefined size due to stack trash because the rect is not zeroed by a default constructor afaik. I'd set these members equal to Source, like so:

```
o.x = x;
o.y = y;
o.w = Source->w;
o.h = Source->h;
```

Comment: thanks but no it didn't do it, the problem is with the whole render thing because when i fill the screen with green through SDL_FillRect it only fills that small square

Comment: Hmm, is clipping enabled? Screen.clip_rect may be small, this can be set with SDL_SetClipRect.

Comment: wait it worked, i don't know why the clip was set to too small in the first place, Thank you very much.

Comment: There seems to be a bug, I set it to 400x400 or 480x640 (by mistake) and it works 440x440, or 640x480 and it doesn't

Comment: If it did work, you should accept the answer and with this give the proper credit back to Sam.